# How to detect Intel's compiler (ICC) with ifdef?

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor, intel, icc

I want to use Intel's current compiler on Linux. I have an inline macro which is supposed to detect the compiler.

It used to work with past versions of GCC and ICC. But now I get `extern inline` with ICC. Does ICC now define `__GNUC__`? How would you detect ICC or Intel's C++ compiler, ICPC?

```
#ifndef INLINE
# if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__GNUG__)
#  define INLINE extern inline
# else
#  define INLINE inline
# endif
#endif
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need that macro at all?

Comment: @delnan: Indeed, it sounds like you're doing something wrong if you need to define `INLINE` like that...

Comment: And yes, icc defines `__GNUC__` because `__GNUC__` does not mean "I am GCC"; it means "I am a compiler for the 'GNU C' language (a superset of standard C)".

Comment: Regarding compatiblity of ICC to GCC you might like to read here: http://software.intel.com/sites/products/collateral/hpc/compilers/intel_linux_compiler_compatibility_with_gnu_compilers.pdf

Comment: Old versions of gcc (e.g. gcc 2.95 and maybe even some versions of gcc 3.x) needed `extern inline` in some cases, but with more recent versions of gcc this kind of hackery shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I am using it for sophisticated numeric's. According to what I read compilers try harder to inline functions if these statements are explicit. Note that I am aware of the different ways to tell compilers about inlining. Indeed I used this initially with gcc in 3.x versions and it used to be very relevant.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`__INTEL_COMPILER` is what you are looking for. (Source: [ICC man page](http://scv.bu.edu/computation/bladecenter/manpages/icc.html))

Answer (score 2):

The following webpage shows information about how to detect recent Intel compilers:

https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/use-predefined-macros-for-specific-code-for-intel-dpcpp-compiler-intel-cpp-compiler-intel-cpp-compiler-classic.html

EDIT (here is the code from the website to differentiate between different versions):

```
// Predefined macros Intel® DPC++ Compiler
// dpcpp only
#if defined(SYCL_LANGUAGE_VERSION) && defined (__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
   // code specific for DPC++ compiler below
   // ... ...

  // example only
   std::cout << "SYCL_LANGUAGE_VERSION: " << SYCL_LANGUAGE_VERSION <<  std::endl;
   std::cout << "__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER: " << __INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER << std::endl;
   std::cout << "__VERSION__: " << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
#endif


 //Predefined Macros for Intel® C++ Compiler
#if !defined(SYCL_LANGUAGE_VERSION) && defined (__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
   // code specific for Intel C++ Compiler below
   // ... ...

   // example only
   std::cout << "__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER: " << __INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER << std::endl;
   std::cout << "__VERSION__: " << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
#endif

// Predefined Macros for Intel® C++ Compiler Classic
// icc/icpc classic only
#if defined(__INTEL_COMPILER)
   // code specific for Intel C++ Compiler Classic below
   // ... ...

   // example only
   std::cout << "__INTEL_COMPILER_BUILD_DATE: " <<   _INTEL_COMPILER_BUILD_DATE << std::endl;
   std::cout << "__INTEL_COMPILER: " << __INTEL_COMPILER << std::endl;
  std::cout << "__VERSION__: " << __VERSION__ << std::endl;
#endif
```

Comment: You should add the important bits to your answer, in case the link goes down someday.

Comment: I was going to complain about your answer using `std::endl` to flush each line separately (instead of a simple `'\n'`), but that problem is present in Intel's original that you got the example from. :/