# Decide if is the user is using gfortran or ifort

Tags: gfortran, intel-fortran

I'm coding a code in modern Fortran, and I want to do some like:

```
IF (you are compiling the code with gfortran) Do something...
IF (you are compiling the code with ifort) Do other thing...
```

but I haven't found a way to verify those logic conditions in the IF statements inside the code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect Intel's compiler (ICC) with ifdef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13534032/how-to-detect-intels-compiler-icc-with-ifdef)

Comment: @veryreverie Not sure that the C pre-processor works in FORTRAN.

Comment: @AdrianMole The Fortran pre-processor can be different to the C pre-processor, but it's identical for something this simple. You just need to use `.F90` file extensions or add the relevant  compiler flag to cause the pre-processor to happen.

Comment: #Ifdef could be very useful as the gfortran and ifort flags are not the same.

Comment: As the gfortran and ifort preprocessors are different, you may want to consider coco?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to look at compiler-specific macros.

For gfortran, you can look at `__GNUC__` as described [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Common-Predefined-Macros.html).

For ifort, you can look at `__INTEL_COMPILER` as described [here](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/m/d/4/1/d/8/icc.txt).

If you have the file `test.F90` (note the `.F90` rather than `.f90`, it's important that this file is preprocessed), then you can have something like

```
program test
  implicit none
  
#ifdef __GNUC__
  logical, parameter :: gfortran = .true.
#else
  logical, parameter :: gfortran = .false.
#endif
  
#ifdef __INTEL_COMPILER
  logical, parameter :: ifort = .true.
#else
  logical, parameter :: ifort = .false.
#endif
  
  if (gfortran) then
    write(*,*) 'gfortran'
  elseif (ifort) then
    write(*,*) 'ifort'
  else
    write(*,*) 'Unknown compiler'
  endif
end program
```